# Definition of $Z_m$ is $[n] = \{x | x \equiv n \pmod m\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, congruences

Any help or sort of input on this question would help a great deal. Thanks

Let $m\in N$. Recall for any integer $n \in Z$, the definition of $[n]$ in $Z_m$ is 
$[n] = \{x | x \equiv n \pmod m\}$. Prove that $Z_m$, for any $a, b, \in Z$, either $[a] = [b]$ or $[a]\cap [b] = \emptyset$.

Comment: *Question in title* Yes. *Body question*: show $a\sim b\iff m\mid b-a$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff What do you mean by the swigly line between a and b? I know it means approximately, but I feel like you have another definition for it.

Comment: $a\sim b$: read $a$ is related to $b$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff How would you prove they're related then?

Comment: He is defining a to be related to b if and only if n divides their difference. Prove that this relation is an equivalence relationship.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** Show that if $[a]\cap[b]\ne\emptyset$ then $[a]=[b]$.

> **Hint 2:** Use the fact that the congruence relation is transitive.